# how to get linkedin feed data into visualforce page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I am trying to integrate LinkedIn on salesforce, i already successfully authorized, got accessToken  and also got my profile info into visulforce page and also post feed into linkedin....and now i want to get feed into vf page how can i get?
this is my method code of getfeed

```
method(){
Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse httpRes = new HttpResponse();
        httpReq.SetMethod('GET');
        httpReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+linkedlnInfoList[0].Access_Token__c);
        httpRes.setHeader('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
        httpReq.setEndpoint('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/activityFeeds?q=networkShares&count=2');
        try{
            httpRes = http.send(httpReq);
            if(httpRes.getStatusCode() == 200){

               // Map<String,object> data = (Map<String,object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(httpRes.getBody());              
                 String response=httpRes.getBody();

            }
```

Error Unknown property controller.response or data

Thanks
Amit Kumar

Comment: `String response=httpRes.getBody();` - this would be method's local variable, not visible outside of the method. Is it really like that or some anonymisation attempt? Make it a class level variable (`public String response {get; private set;}`) otherwise Visualforce won't be able to see it?

Comment: thanks...but after doing this i am not getting json data in the pageblock table....in browser console "Get 404 not found"...